# ListView Recycling and Withholding Drawing of Elements Until They're Completely Loaded

Tags: android, listview

Two questions:

a) is there any way to stop views from getting "thrown out" when you scroll? I'm fetching images from the web using the YouTubeAPI (YouTubeThumbnailView) and it takes some time to fetch these - when scrolling the images are loaded in a couple seconds after scrolling has stopped.

and b) can I withhold elements of the listview until they are completely loaded? I'd prefer the elements to render when their thumbnails have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're going about this the wrong way. You should be fetching the images and storing them in some sort of cache (there are numerous topics on this, so I'll leave that part as an exercise) and then notifying when the data has loaded and updating the thumbnail if it's still on screen. It shouldn't matter whether the View was "thrown out"; on the next time you try to View that particular thumbnail it should already be in the cache and should be able to be loaded near-instantly.

As for the second question, you could initially set the visibility of the View that you return in your Adapter's `getView()` to INVISIBLE, then when you display the thumbnail, set the thumbnail and then set the View to VISIBLE.

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to obtain the thumbnail through the YouTubeAPI as it takes care of thumbnail population.